# Virtual Memory - calculate number of pages in page table

Tags: memory, virtual, page-tables

- Virtual address space is 64bits
- Page size is 64KB
- Word size is 4bytes

How many pages are in the page table?

At first I thought:

page size = 64KB = 2^16bytes, so the offset uses 16 bits of the 64
Therefore, 48 bits left -> there are 2^48 pages in the page table
(I didn't understand where to use the info about the word size)
However, the correct answer is that there are 2^50 pages, which confuses me..

Then I thought that maybe the page offset is only 14bits because the word size is 4bytes = 2^2bytes. so there are really 2^50 pages in the pagetable.

Am I right? can I get a better explanation?

Comment: When you post a question, verify the preview before posting. Unreadable question have less chance to be unanswered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each page uses 14 bits of the 64, not 16 as the minimum addressable unit is a 4 byte word (which effectively removes 2 bits off the number needed). So the offset has the remaining 50 bits left.

Comment: Don't you mean 14? (4 bytes is 2^2. 16 - 2 = 14)

Comment: @ron: fixed - My counting is a little off today, and I was typing this just before a meeting and didn't proof read. :D